# Complete LAMP package

Tags: mysql, php, httpd, lamp

I was told to install a LAMP setup on one of our Red Hat servers by my boss. I started by installing the generic httpd, php and mysql packages but he keeps telling me there is one package that automatically installs all of them. Including forcing correct dependencies and ensuring compatibility between them.

Has anyone heard of a Red Hat package like this?

Comment: You *don't* want that. Install exactly what you need and not a bit more.

Comment: There are options when installing the OS to have it also install a LAMP stack. I don't think there is a single LAMP package though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He may be thinking of `yum` groups, but even then there's not just one group that does everything you want.  Try

```
yum groupinstall "Web Server"
yum groupinstall "MySQL Database server"
yum groupinstall "PHP Support"
```

That said, what you're doing is also fine: `yum`'s job is to manage dependencies, so doing `yum install httpd` will automatically pull in everything httpd actually **needs**, in the correct versions, provided your repositories are set up correctly.  You may find that the group installs bring in extra tools that you didn't know you needed, but can be of use in running such a server.

Comment: Perfect, I think this is what he was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

On a Red Hat based system, there actually is no such package which will pull in everything necessary for a basic LAMP stack. A minute or so with `repoquery` is sufficient to demonstrate this.

To install such a stack, you need at minimum:

```
httpd php php-mysql mysql-server
```